# Change WPF Calendar control day name format

Tags: wpf, calendar, string-formatting

I am currently using WPF Calendar control. The Day names are displayed as Su, Mo, Tu, etc. But I want those to be displayed as Sun, Mon, Tue, etc.. I found there is no data template property to achieve this one.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this and unfortunately, I don't think that you will be able to achieve what you want.

To start with, I found the `StringFormat` to show three character day names in the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page at MSDN:

```
StringFormat=ddd
```

Then I thought that you might find a solution for the rest of your problem in the [Custom date format for WPF Calendar CalendarItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230628/custom-date-format-for-wpf-calendar-calendaritems) post. So, adapting the idea from @Quartermeister, I could tried the following:

```
<Calendar>
    <Calendar.CalendarButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="primitives:CalendarButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="primitives:CalendarButton">
                        <primitives:CalendarButton>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day, StringFormat=ddd}"/>
                        </primitives:CalendarButton>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarButtonStyle>
</Calendar>
```

As you can imagine, I was way off because this answered a different problem. So I went back to MSDN to find [the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Calendar` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468218.aspx) to experiment further. If you look at that `ControlTemplate`, you will see a `Style` named `CalendarItemStyle`.

In that `Style` is a `ControlTemplate` and in its `Resources` section, you will see a `DataTemplate` with the key `{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}`. Finally, in that `DataTemplate`, you will see the `TextBlock` that is responsible for displaying the day names:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="#FF333333"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   FontSize="9.5"
                   FontFamily="Verdana"
                   Margin="0,6,0,6"
                   Text="{Binding}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

I increased the size of the day names, so we can be sure that that is the correct `TextBlock`. (Ignore the odd looking `Button`s at the top - they are just like that because I didn't copy their `ControlTemplate`s):

[image]

Now if you look at the `Binding` in that `TextBlock`, you will see that unfortunately, it is set to `{Binding}`. This means that it is using the whole data bound value, rather than setting a particular `StringFormat` on a `DateTime` object. This means that we cannot use a `StringFormat` because the data bound value is already a `string`.

Comment: Thanks Sheridian. But this is horrible.

Comment: While Microsoft's approach to this part of the control was definitely poor, I'm guessing that they thought that we couldn't fit any more than two letters in that space, and if that's true then they *did* have a point there.

Comment: "Two letters in that space" may OK for default template. But if someone want to customize the template, this is not good.

Comment: I completely agree... I was just searching for some logical reason why they might have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it with following converter,

```
public class CalendarDayNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var daynames = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
        string dayname = value.ToString();

        return daynames.First(t => t.StartsWith(dayname)).Substring(0, 3);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you use the converter? I also want to format day names like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here, but I came up with a slightly different solution that, hopefully, will work a bit more reliably internationally. It's a two part thing. First, make a template for the day name as mentioned by @Sheridan above:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}">
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CalendarDayNameConverter}">
                <Binding Path="(Grid.Column)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Mode="OneWay"/>
                <Binding Path="FirstDayOfWeek" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Calendar}}" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Of course, format it as per your requirements. The trick here is that the `Text` is bound to `Grid.Column` instead of the usual data context value (the two-letter day name provided by WPF). The grid column number is set by internal [WPF logic](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/CalendarItem.cs,963) and should be reliable. We have to use an `IMultiValueConverter` because we depend on the `FirstDayOfWeek` value from the parent `Calendar` control too:

```cs
public sealed class CalendarDayNameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values?.Length > 0 && values[0] is int index)
        {
            var dayNames = culture?.DateTimeFormat?.AbbreviatedDayNames;
            if (dayNames?.Length > 0)
            {
                var firstDayOfWeek = values.Length > 1 && values[1] is DayOfWeek d ? d : culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
                return dayNames[(index + (int)firstDayOfWeek) % dayNames.Length];
            }
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into it aswell.

The only solution I have seen was localizing the calendar with a custom localisation dictionary, but unfortunately there are no keys given, we could use.

Decompiling the calendar control I found out, that the calendar control uses a native function (nativeGetCalendarData()) to localize the calendar, so I wont be able to retrieve those keys the easy way :(

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site [nullskull.com](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1382/styling-the-wpf-calendar-to-resemble-outlooks-month-view-calendar.aspx). The Downloadable Source contain a day name converter and description