# Calendar. How to change names of week in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I would like to change the days of the week in the calendar.
I found that the names of the days of the week are bound here

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}">
   <TextBlock Foreground="#FF333333"
              FontWeight="Bold"
              FontSize="9.5"
              FontFamily="Verdana"
              Margin="0,6,0,6"
              Text="{Binding}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I change the xaml code so that each TextBlock displays the name of the day of the week ?

Below is the full code from Microsoft.

```xml
<Style x:Key="CalendarItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
  <Setter Property="Margin"
          Value="0,3,0,3" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}">
            <TextBlock Foreground="#FF333333"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       FontSize="9.5"
                       FontFamily="Verdana"
                       Margin="0,6,0,6"
                       Text="{Binding}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="PART_Root">
          <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledColor"
                             Color="#A5FFFFFF" />
          </Grid.Resources>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                   To="1"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  CornerRadius="1">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    CornerRadius="1">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton"
                        Template="{StaticResource PreviousButtonTemplate}"
                        Focusable="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Height="20"
                        Width="28" />
                <Button x:Name="PART_HeaderButton"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Focusable="False"
                        FontSize="10.5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}" />
                <Button x:Name="PART_NextButton"
                        Focusable="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Template="{StaticResource NextButtonTemplate}"
                        Height="20"
                        Width="28" />
                <Grid x:Name="PART_MonthView"
                      Visibility="Visible"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="6,-1,6,6"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="PART_YearView"
                      Visibility="Hidden"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Margin="6,-3,7,6">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Border>
          </Border>
          <Rectangle x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual"
                     Fill="{StaticResource DisabledColor}"
                     Opacity="0"
                     RadiusY="2"
                     RadiusX="2"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Stroke="{StaticResource DisabledColor}"
                     StrokeThickness="1"
                     Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"
                    Value="Visible" />
          </Trigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisplayMode, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
              AncestorType={x:Type Calendar}}}"
                       Value="Year">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="PART_MonthView"
                    Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="PART_YearView"
                    Value="Visible" />
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisplayMode, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
              AncestorType={x:Type Calendar}}}"
                       Value="Decade">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="PART_MonthView"
                    Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="PART_YearView"
                    Value="Visible" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, I tried to implement what I wanted, but it didn't work

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what your asking. instead of integer values, do you want to display texts as Monday, Tuesday etc. ?

Comment: By default, the day of the week is displayed as Mon, but I want Monday, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377248/change-wpf-calendar-control-day-name-format